# Unable to compile veins simulation, fatal error: veins/veins.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, omnet++, veins

I could use some help/tips on how to resolve this veins error. Thank you in advance for any tips or help.

I'm trying to build veins 5.2 examples using omnet++ under linux ubuntu 22. First, I get the following error in a dialog pop up.

> Plug-in org.omnetpp.main was unable to load class
> org.omnetpp.ide.variables.NedPathResolver. An error occurred while
> automatically activating bundle org.omnetpp.main (360).

In addition, in the Console in omnet++ I get this error:

```
18:20:18 **** Incremental Build of configuration gcc-release for
project veins_inet3 **** make MODE=release all  make[1]: Entering
directory '/veins/veins-veins-5.2/subprojects/veins_inet3/src'
veins_inet/VeinsInetManager.cc In file included from
./veins_inet/VeinsInetManager.h:25,
                 from veins_inet/VeinsInetManager.cc:23: ./veins_inet/veins_inet.h:25:10: fatal error: veins/veins.h: No such
file or directory make[1]: Leaving directory
'/veins/veins-veins-5.2/subprojects/veins_inet3/src'    25 | #include
"veins/veins.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. make[1]: *** [Makefile:114: ../out/gcc-release/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetManager.o]
Error 1 make: *** [Makefile:36: all] Error 2 "make MODE=release all"
terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

**How can I successfully build the simulation from within omnet++ and include the correct search path for veins.h?**

I'm familiar with -I CFLAGs for Makefiles. But, I do not know where to put the path within onmnet++ interface. I do see the file src/veins/veins.h exists.

To test and compare to linux, I have also successfully built omnet++ under windows11. But, I am unable to fix the error within linux which is where I need to run my simulations.

Here are a few sides notes, that I suspect are unrelated to this build error:

- I'm also running Docker and VNC'ing into a container w/ veins.
- I need to be able to run veins within a linux environment to connect the
  sims to other technologies (for school research).
- I compiled omnet++ without OSG open scene graph or OSGearth 2.7. I do not need 3d and
  OSGearch 2.7 was being troublesome.